# How to log out of my facebook app but not facebook using javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, logout

I have searched for this and the answers were VERY unclear and outdated.

So - I am using Facebook Javascript SDK to allow people to log in and out of my site. When they log out, I want them to be able to stay logged in to Facebook.

I am using standard code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '#######',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }

</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button data-auto-logout-link="true" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not possible. And the reason is that someone may go to your site and login using Facebook which means that they are also logged in on Facebook. So when they logout they also need to be logged out from Facebook

Comment: Not impossible. Check out the website http://www.myfitnesspal.com

Answer (score 3):

PERFECT! I figured it out on my own. The answer is two part. You need to revoke access. You do this like this in your javascript:

```
  function logoutFacebook()
  {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token 
            // and signed request each expire
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

            FB.api('/'+uid+'/permissions', 'delete', function(response){});

          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
          } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
          }
         });
  }
```

Then, you add a button to fire off that function:

```
<button id="logout" onclick="logoutFacebook()">Logout</button>
```

Comment: You didn't log the user out. And as I said there is a reason you get logged out of Facebook also.

Comment: That's wrong, it contradict with the question line, this will de-authorize your app , not log out!